# Retrieve rows with a given set of values and no others

Tags: select, db2, zos, db2-zos

Working with Db2 on z/OS.

Consider a simple example of an ORDER table and a child ORDER_ITEM table. the PK for the child is ORD_NUM plus PART_NUM.
I want to find the rows in the ORDER_ITEM table with parts that have only a certain set of PART_NUM values and no other.
So for example, if the parts I'm interested in are

```
PART1, PART2
```

and the ORDER_ITEM table has rows like so

```
ORD1 PART1
ORD1 PART2
ORD2 PART1
ORD3 PART2
ORD4 PART1
ORD4 PART2
ORD4 PART3
```

A query like

```
SELECT blah FROM ORDER_ITEM WHERE PART_NUM IN ('PART1', 'PART2')
```

would correctly return ORD1, ORD2, ORD3, it would also incorrectly return ORD4.

I am working with Db2 on z/OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select oi.*
from order_item oi
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_item oi2
                  where oi2.order_num = oi.order_num and
                        oi2.part_num not in ('PART1', 'PART2')
                 );
```

That is, get all the rows in the table where the order has not part that is not in the specified list of parts.

Comment: Thanks very much.

You know, instinctively, I would have written

`select oi.*
from order_item oi
where 
oi.part_num  in ('PART1', 'PART2')
and
not exists (select 1
                  from order_item oi2
                  where oi2.order_num = oi.order_num and
                        oi2.part_num not in ('PART1', 'PART2')
                 );`

But evidently I don't need that first predicate and am just having a hard time wrapping my head around it even while it produces the result I want!